# How to Optimize and Scale Ruby on Rails App with Nginx and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have an app in production which uses `Ruby on Rails` with `Nginx` and `Passenger`, the performance is good at the start but as the time goes by (after an hour or more) it slows down, I need to restart the Nginx for it to increase its performance again. May I know how to make it more optimize and scalable and avoid in keep on restarting. Thanks, guys need your help so bad.

Answer (score 3):

There are some settings you can do to optimize your `Nginx` server.

If you have `root access` to your server and have `Nginx` correctly added, you can consider some changes.

**1)** Run `sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` & consider these settings based on what are your needs *(don't replace the whole code into your server as some of the default setting are not here. Just add ones you neeed)*:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        multi_accept on;
        use                 epoll;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        client_body_timeout 500s;
        client_header_timeout 500s;
        keepalive_timeout 500s;
        send_timeout 300s;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        client_max_body_size 100000M;
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log off;
        #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
                gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_min_length  10240;
        gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

}
```

*You can change the numbers based on your application and needs.*

**2)** Run `sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` & consider these settings based on what are your needs *(don't replace the whole code into your server as some of the default setting are not here. Just add ones you neeed)*:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        passenger_enabled on;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(js)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires 150d;
    }
    location ~*  \.(css)$ {
        access_log        off;
        log_not_found     off;
        expires 150d;
    }
}
```

*You can change the numbers based on your application and needs.*

*Remember to `restart ngnix` after changes.*

Again be careful to what you add or remove and again **DO NOT** copy & paste the whole code as some default settings are not here.

One other thing would be take a look at your `logs` & `tmp` files/folder as you can eliminate logs to take less memory and space. You can also take a look `tmp` folder and settings.

You can also consider *(recommended)* doing caching in your views. As you know rails has **[Fragment and Russian doll caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)**. Caching will always help boosting response time.

If you are not familier with caching, there is also something called *progressive rendering*. You can use `gem 'progressive_render'` and [watch this toturial](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/progressive-render).

Hope it helps.

Comment: No problem. If this helped you, I appreciate if you upvote and accept as your answer